# How to filter data between two dataframes within the date range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have two dataframes df1 and df2 as below:

df1

```
Start_Date  End_Date    KGS
20191021    20191031    1759
20191101    20191130    36191
20191201    20191231    25953
20200101    20200131    49085
20200201    20200228    9153
```

df2

```
        id    scene_id origin   tea_item    week_commencing
0   1762333097  3279    JA       AB21JA      05-01-2020 
1   1762333098  3279    JA       AB21JA      26-04-2020 
2   1762333099  3279    JA       AB21JA      09-02-2020 
3   1762333100  3279    JA       AB21JA      19-01-2020 
4   1762333101  3279    JA       AB21JA      29-12-2019
```

Now I need to filter the df2 dataframe where `df2.week_commencing` was in between the `df1.Start_Date` and `df1.End_Date`

Answer (score 0):

Convert all datetimelike columns to `datetimes`, use cross join by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and last filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df1['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df2['week_commencing'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['week_commencing'])

df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df1.assign(a=1), on='a')
df = df[df.week_commencing.between(df.Start_Date,df.End_Date)].drop('a', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure that in both lists `Start_Date`, `End_Date` and `week_commercing` are of type datetime.This can be achieved by using the [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) 
  function.

  `pd.to_datetime(df1['Start_Date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')`
  `pd.to_datetime(df2['week_commercing'], format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='ignore')`
- Now that all of your columns are in date format we can compare them and make selection

  `df2[df2['week_commercing'] > df1['Start_Date'] and df2['week_commercing'] < df1['End_Date']]`

Comment: Got an Error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects